# VisualStyles color inconsistancy

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm just messing about with the Visual Styles offered by .NET using Winforms and I have a problem. I am simply executing this code, called from the OnPaint method of a custom Panel, nothing special.

```
private void DrawBox(PaintEventArgs e)
{
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, ComboBoxState.Normal);}
```

My problem is that the Background Color of the Button is grey while the Background Color of a true ComboBox is white (on my Computer anyway).

Two questions here, why the Color change and how do I make my Button render using the same Background Color as a true ComboBox?

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Are you also messing around with enabling/disabling `VisualStyles` settings and `SetWindowTheme()` and Co.?

Comment: The combobox style is heavily affected by the DropdownStyle property, compare DropDown vs DropDownList.  You don't like ComboBoxRender considering DropDownList being the "true" style.  Lars fixed your problem, please close your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClipRectangle is not what you want.  Set the actual rectangle you want to draw.  That being said, yeah, using VisualStyles is going to make you mad.  This will get you close:

```
VisualStyleRenderer vsr = new VisualStyleRenderer("EDIT", 1, 1);
vsr.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, controlRectangle);
vsr.SetParameters("COMBOBOX", 7, 1);
vsr.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, arrowRectangle);
```

Comment: Probably better use the internal definition for parameters: `VisualStyleElement ButtonElm = VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Normal;`  and `VisualStyleElement TextElm = VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit.Normal;` ([Element].Part and [Element].State ). `[ComboBoxRenderer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the (base - no DPI thingy considered) definitions of the ComboBox parts area.

Comment: Excruciating technicality, 7 is the part number for the button on the left, 6 for the button on the right.  You'd have to pay attention to the form's RightToLeft property.  Very hard to imagine it actually matters :)

Comment: @LarsTech, what I want is to mess about with Visual Styles, not really concerned with actual rectangle so my example really is what I want, as I don't care about the size of the control. That said your code works great except for the typo in line 2, there's one to many braces. Thanks

Comment: @Jimi, VisualStyleElement.ComboBox,DropDown.Normal draws the button with a grey background which is what motivated the questions in the first place.

Comment: @dannyhut  You missed the point of that comment. Probably because you didn't open the link provided. You are painting a Panel and using it's e.Graphics object to paint the Combo (partial) parts. This is just a painting, not a control. It doesn't have a Handle, which can be passed to [SetWindowTheme()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) to apply the current theme. (...).

Comment: @dannyhut  (...) The [ComboBoxRenderer.DrawBackground](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBoxRenderer.cs,152) calls VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground(), passing the DeviceContext (the Graphics object of a Control) on which the drawing will occur.  DrawBackground() calls [DrawThemeBackground()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground), which paints the requested parts **Of a Panel DeviceContext**. Here: `("COMBOBOX", 7, 1)` you can set any *number*. Always a Panel part.

Comment: @Jimi. ComboBoxRenderer draws the button grey as stated. I had already tried to use this class before I asked the original question. Sorry I didn't make that clear, I had just come off night shift, I'm a nurse by day.